# Date-String parsing problem (due to months from 0 to 11)

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

The code

```
    String strDate = "2010-12-01";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
    System.out.println(parsedDate);
```

will, dependend on your locale, produce the following output:

```
Fri Jan 01 00:12:00 CET 2010
```

The date is not parsed correctly, since i expect the 1st dec and not the 1st jan.
I know, months are numbered from 0 to 11, so the 12 becomes a 0 for january.

I have several solutions for this problem in mind, but all of them will produce at least 3-4 additional lines of code. So my question is:

**What is the nicest way to solve this "problem"?**

I can't imagine that it takes more than 2-3 lines to parse a simple date...

//edit: Shame on me for this question. Forgive me.  thx folks

Comment: Incorrect diagnosis. `mm` is minutes. That is why you are getting 12 minutes (which should have given a hint).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy-MM-dd`

---

```
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07  

m   Minute in hour  Number  30
```

**See**

- [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 5):

Your date format is incorrect: Months are `MM` (not `mm`, which is for minutes). Try this:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd"
```

The reason you are getting January is that you haven't given a month to the parser (you gave *year-minute-day*). January, the first month, is the default month allocated to the date if not provided by the input. The `12` got parsed into the minute field (fairly obviously)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the nicest way to solve this "problem"?

Use different classes. You are using troublesome old legacy classes. Instead use the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. It counts months sensibly, 1-12 is January through December.

Your input string is already in one of the ISO 8601 formats. These standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes. So no need with defining a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2010-12-01" );
```

## `Month`

Also check out the handy [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
Month month = Month.of( 1 ); // January = 1, December = 12.
```